# Magento 2: Open Popup Modal on Button Click in Admin Grid

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, ajax, popup

**UPDATED**

I'm using `Magento 2.4`, I want to open a popup modal to display some info, currently, when I hit the button I am redirected to `phtml` file but I want to open a popup on the same page. I have a column in sale_order_grid, and in that column, I have a button like:

[image]

`app/code/Tekglide/GoFlyy/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="goflyy" frontName="goflyy">
            <module name="Tekglide_GoFlyy"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

`app/code/Tekglide/GoFlyy/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <actionsColumn name="goflyy_order_id" class="Tekglide\GoFlyy\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\GoFlyyGetOrder">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>                    
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">GoFlyy Order ID</item>
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

`app/code/Tekglide/GoFlyy/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/GoFlyyGetOrder.php`

```
<?php
namespace Tekglide\GoFlyy\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;

class GoFlyyGetOrder extends Column
{
   public $urlBuilder;

   public $layout;

   protected $orderRepository;

   public function __construct(
       ContextInterface $context,
       UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
       UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
       \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface $layout,
       \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
       array $components = [],
       array $data = []
   ) {
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        $this->layout = $layout;
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
   }

   public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
   {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $urlInterface = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\UrlInterface');
         

        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
           $fieldName = $this->getData('name');
           foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $order  = $this->orderRepository->get($item["entity_id"]);
                $goFlyyOrderId = $order->getData("goflyy_order_id");                
                if($goFlyyOrderId){
                    $item[$fieldName] = '<a href="'.$urlInterface->getUrl('flyy/index/index').'"><button class="button" id="FlyyOrderId_'.$goFlyyOrderId.'">'.$goFlyyOrderId.'</button>';
                    // $item[$fieldName] = '<a href="'.$urlInterface->getUrl('flyy/index/index',['_current' => true,'_use_rewrite' => true, '_query' => $queryParams]).'"><button class="button" id="FlyyOrderId_'.$goFlyyOrderId.'">'.$goFlyyOrderId.'</button>';
                }
           }
       }

       return $dataSource;
   }
}
```

`app/code/Tekglide/GoFlyy/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright ©  All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Tekglide\GoFlyy\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index implements HttpGetActionInterface
{

    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(PageFactory $resultPageFactory)
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Execute view action
     *
     * @return ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    }
}
?>
```

`app/code/Tekglide/GoFlyy/Block/Adminhtml/Index/Index.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright ©  All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Tekglide\GoFlyy\Block\Adminhtml\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template
{
    protected $request;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
        parent::__construct($context,$data);
    }

    public function getFlyyOrderId(){
        // $FlyyOrderId = $this->request->getParam('id', false);
        $FlyyOrderId = '331';

        return $FlyyOrderId;
    }
}
?>
```

`app/code/Tekglide/GoFlyy/view/adminhtml/layout/goflyy_index_index.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block name="index.index" class="Tekglide\GoFlyy\Block\Adminhtml\Index\Index" template="Tekglide_GoFlyy::index/index.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

`app/code/Tekglide/GoFlyy/view/adminhtml/templates/index/index.phtml`

```
<div id="popup-modal-main<?php echo $block->getFlyyOrderId();?>" style="display:none;">
       Fly Order Id <?php echo $block->getFlyyOrderId();?>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
require([
    'jquery', 
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
    ], function($, modal) {            
        $(document).ready(function(){  
            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                title: 'Open Modal'
            };              
            $("#FlyyOrderId_<?php echo $block->getFlyyOrderId();?>").on('click',function(){                                                                               
                $("#popup-modal-main<?php echo $block->getFlyyOrderId();?>").modal(options).modal('openModal');
            });
        });
    });        
</script>
```

**`ERROR:`** When I hit the button I redirected to Dashboard with a message, `Invalid security or form key. Please refresh the page.`.

What I want to do is I want to trigger an Ajax request on this button click, whatever response I get. I'll display it in a popup modal.

Answer (score 2):

Add component in column in grid layout file and add js and class file path

```
<column name="goflyy_order_id" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Goflyy">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
<item name="config" xsi:type="array">
<item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/grid/columns/goflyy</item>
<item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
<item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
<item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">120</item>
<item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Goflyy Order Id</item>
</item>
</argument>
</column>
```

Add data in grid row using UI

```
<?php 
namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey;

class Goflyy extends Column
{

    private $urlBuilder;
    private $formKey;

    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        FormKey $formKey,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        $this->formKey = $formKey;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $name = $this->getData('name');
                if (isset($item['entity_id'])) {
                    $item[$name . '_html'] = "<button class='button'><span>".__("Send Email")."</span></button>";
                    $item[$name . '_title'] = __('Send  Email');
                    $item[$name . '_entity_id'] = $item['entity_id'];
                    $item[$name . '_code'] = $item['code'];
                    $item[$name . '_link_one'] = $item['link_one'];
                    $item[$name . '_link_two'] = $item['link_two'];
                    $item[$name . '_formkry'] = $this->formKey->getFormKey();
                    $item[$name . '_formaction'] = $this->urlBuilder->getUrl('route/action/controller');
                }
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Create app/code/Vendor/Module/view/base/web/js/grid/columns/goflyy.js

```
define([‘Magento_Ui / js / grid / columns / column’, ‘jquery’, ‘mage / template’, ‘mage / validation’, ‘text!IntegerByte_Popup / templates / grid / cells / sendemail / sendemail.html’, ‘Magento_Ui / js / modal / modal’], function(Column, $, mageTemplate, validation, sendmailPreviewTemplate) {
    ‘
    use strict’;

    return Column.extend({
        defaults: {
            bodyTmpl: ‘ui / grid / cells / html’,
            fieldClass: {
                ‘
                data - grid - html - cell’: true
            }
        },
        gethtml: function(row) {
            return row[this.index + ‘_html’];
        },
        getFormaction: function(row) {
            return row[this.index + ‘_formaction’];
        },

        getFormkey: function(row) {
            return row[this.index + ‘_formkry’];
        },

        getEntityid: function(row) {
            return row[this.index + ‘_entity_id’];
        },
        getLabel: function(row) {
            return row[this.index + ‘_html’]
        },
        getTitle: function(row) {
            return row[this.index + ‘_title’]
        },
        getCode: function(row) {
            return row[this.index + ‘_code’]
        },

        getLinkOne: function(row) {
            return row[this.index + ‘_link_one’]
        },
        getLinkTwo: function(row) {
            return row[this.index + ‘_link_one’]
        },
        preview: function(row) {
            var modalHtml = mageTemplate(
                sendmailPreviewTemplate, {
                    html: this.gethtml(row),
                    title: this.getTitle(row),
                    label: this.getLabel(row),
                    formaction: this.getFormaction(row),
                    formakey: this.getFormkey(row),
                    code: this.getCode(row),
                    linkTwo: this.getLinkTwo(row),
                    linkOne: this.getLinkOne(row),
                    entityid: this.getEntityid(row),
                    name: $.mage.__(‘Name’),
                    email: $.mage.__(‘Email’),
                    message: $.mage.__(‘Comment’),
                    selectlink: $.mage.__(‘Please select’),
                    demo1option: $.mage.__(‘demo1’),
                    demo2option: $.mage.__(‘demo2’)

                }
            );
            var previewPopup = $(‘ < div / > ’).html(modalHtml);
            previewPopup.modal({
                title: $.mage.__(this.getTitle(row)),
                innerScroll: true,
                modalClass: ‘_email - box’,
                buttons: [{
                    type: ’submit’,
                    text: $.mage.__(‘Send Now’),
                    class: ‘action close - popup wide’,
                    click: function() {
                        $(“form”).validation().submit();
                    }
                }]
            }).trigger(‘openModal’);
        },
        getFieldHandler: function(row) {
            return this.preview.bind(this, row);
        }
    });
});
```

Create app/code/Vendor/Magento/view/base/web/templates/grid/cells/goflyy.html

```
<form id=”send-mail-form-<%- entityid %>” method=”post” enctype=”multipart/form-data” action=”<%- formaction %>”
data-hasrequired=”* Required Fields” data-mage-init='{“validation”:{}}’>
<div class=”modal-body”>
<div class=”bootbox-body”>
   <div class=”admin__field field required”>
      <label for=”name-<%- entityid %>” class=”admin__field-label label”><span><%- name %></span></label>
      <div class=”admin__field-control control”>
         <input type=”email” name=”email” id=”email_address-<%- entityid %>” value=”” title=”Email”
         class=”admin__control-text required” data-validate=”{required:true, ‘validate-email’:true}”
         required>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

**1) Update GoFlyyGetOrder.php Add id in Button and a tag

Vendor/Module/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/GoFlyyGetOrder.php**

```
public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            $fieldName = $this->getData('name');
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $order  = $this->orderRepository->get($item["entity_id"]);
                $goFlyyOrderId = $order->getData("goflyy_order_id");
                if($goFlyyOrderId){
                    $item[$fieldName] = "<a href='baseurl/Vendor_Module/index/index?id='.$goFlyyOrderId><button class='button' id='FlyyOrderId_$goFlyyOrderId$'><span>$goFlyyOrderId</span></button>";
                }
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
```

**After Call Phtml in Sales Order Grid**

**1) Create a File and add the code given below 

File : Vendor/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright ©  All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index implements HttpGetActionInterface
{

    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(PageFactory $resultPageFactory)
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Execute view action
     *
     * @return ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    }
}
?>
```

**2) Create a block class and add a code 

File : Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Index/Index.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright ©  All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template
{

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context  $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $this->request = $request;
            $context,$data
        );
    }
    public function getFlyyOrderId(){
        $FlyyOrderId = $this->request->getParam('id', false);
        return $FlyyOrderId;
    }
}
?>
```

**3) Create a vendor_module_index_index.xml 

File : Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/vendor_module_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block name="index.index" class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Index\Index" template="Vendor_Module::index/index.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**4) Create a template file flyorder.phtml in path 

File : Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Index\Index" template="Vendor_Module::index/index.phtml"**

```
<div id="popup-modal-main<?php echo $block->getFlyyOrderId();?>" style="display:none;">
       Fly Order Id <?php echo $block->getFlyyOrderId();?>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
require([
    'jquery', 
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
    ], function($, modal) {            
        $(document).ready(function(){  
            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                title: 'Open Modal'
            };              
            $("#FlyyOrderId_<?php echo $block->getFlyyOrderId();?>").on('click',function(){                                                                               
                $("#popup-modal-main<?php echo $block->getFlyyOrderId();?>").modal(options).modal('openModal');
            });
        });
    });        
</script>
```

Comment: Naeem question updated.